# Need to sort a string input by the most frequent characters first in C (qsort)

Tags: c, sorting

I managed to sort it alphabetically but I need to sort it by the most frequent characters first after that. Since I'm new to C programming Im not sure if this alphabetical sort is needed. Also I thought about using a struct but not sure how to do the whole process with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return *(char*)a - *(char*)b;
}

void AlphabetOrder(char str[]) {
    qsort(str, (size_t) strlen(str), (size_t) sizeof(char), cmpfunc);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}

void Max_Occurring(char *str)
{
    int i;
    int max = 0;

    int freq[256] = {0};

    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        freq[str[i]] = freq[str[i]] + 1;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if(freq[i] > freq[max])
        {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    printf("Character '%c' appears %d times", max, freq[max], str);
}

int main() {
    char str1[20];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", &str1);

    AlphabetOrder(str1);
    Max_Occurring(str1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to sort a string by max occurring characters and resolve ties by alphabetical order or the opposite? A example case with the expected result would be welcome here.

Comment: If instead, you have an array of `struct` with members `letter` (set that up first, same as array index) and `count` you can sort *that* array and output `count` of each `letter`.

Comment: bigjumpsse, Aside: casts not needed with `(size_t) strlen(str), (size_t) sizeof(char)`.  `strlen()` and `sizeof` result in type `size_t` already.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote you a frequency sorter using the idea that @WeatherVane mentioned:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct cfreq {
    unsigned char c;
    int freq;
};

int freqcmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    struct cfreq *a2 = (struct cfreq *) a;
    struct cfreq *b2 = (struct cfreq *) b;
    if(a2->freq < b2->freq) return -1;
    if(a2->freq == b2->freq) return 0;
    return 1;
}

int freqcmpdesc(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return -freqcmp(a, b);
}

void FrequencyOrder(const char str[]) {
    struct cfreq cfreqs[256];
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(cfreqs) / sizeof(*cfreqs); i++) {
        cfreqs[i].c = i;
        cfreqs[i].freq = 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++) cfreqs[str[i]].freq++;
    qsort(cfreqs, sizeof(cfreqs) / sizeof(*cfreqs), sizeof(*cfreqs), freqcmpdesc);
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(cfreqs) / sizeof(*cfreqs); i++) {
        if(cfreqs[i].freq) printf("%c", cfreqs[i].c);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    char str1[20];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", &str1);
    FrequencyOrder(str1);
    return 0;
}
```

and here is a sample session (note: output is not deterministic for letters with same frequency):

```
Enter a string: buzz
zbu
```

If you want duplicate letters in the output then replace the print with a loop along these lines:

```
while(cfreqs[i].freq--) printf("%c", cfreqs[i].c);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Im not sure if this alphabetical sort is needed.

It is not *needed*, yet if done, `Max_Occurring()` can take advantage of a sorted string.

Since the string is sorted before calling `Max_Occurring()`, compute the max occurring via a count of adjacent repetitions of each `char`.

```
// Untested illustrative code.
// str points to a sorted string.
void Max_Occurring(const char *str) {
  char max_ch = '\0';
  size_t max_occurence = 0;

  char previous = '\0';
  size_t occurrence = 0;

  while (*str) {
    if (*str == previous) {
      occurrence++; 
    } else {
      occurrence = 1; 
    } 

    if (occurrence > max_occurence) {
      max_occurence = occurrence;
      max_ch = *str;   
    } 

    previous = *str;
    str++;
  }
  printf("Character '%c' appears %zu times", max_ch, max_occurence);
}
```

In the case of multiple characters with the same max occurrence, this code only reports one max.

---

**Avoid buffer overflow**

Do not use `scanf("%s"...` without a *width* limit.

Tip: enable all warnings to save time and see the problem of using `&str1` when `str1` should be used.

```
char str1[20];
...
// scanf("%s", &str1);
scanf("%19s", str1);
```

**Avoid a negative index**

If still wanting to for a frequency table, watch out for the case when `char` is *signed* and code use `str[i] < 0` to index an array.

Instead:

```
const unsigned char *ustr = (const unsigned char *) str;

size_t freq[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {0};

for(size_t i = 0; ustr[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    freq[ustr[i]]++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative that may be simpler.

```
void freqOrder( char *p ) {
#define ASCIIcnt 128  // 7bit ASCII

    // to count occurences of each character
    int occur[ ASCIIcnt ];
    memset( occur, 0, sizeof occur );

    int maxCnt = 0; // remember the highest count

    // do the counting
    for( ; *p; p++ )
        if( ++occur[ *p ] > maxCnt )
            maxCnt = occur[ *p ];

    // output most frequent to least frequen
    for( ; maxCnt; maxCnt-- )
        for( int i = 0; i < ASCIIcnt; i++ )
            if( occur[i] == maxCnt )
                while( occur[i]-- )
                    putchar( i );
    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main( void ) {
    freqOrder( "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" );
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
'        ooooeeehhrruuTabcdfgijklmnpqstvwxyz'
```